# Using `delay` in Sidekiq with dynamic class/method names

Tags: actionmailer, sidekiq

Let's say I have some internal business logic that determines what mailer needs to be sent.

The output of this business logic is a Hash in the following format -

```
{ mailer_class: SomeMailer, mailer_method: "foo_email" }
{ mailer_class: OtherMailer, mailer_method: "bar_email" }
# etc...
```

I need to call the appropriate mailer based on the info above so I try something like this with Sidekiq's built in `delay` -

```
data = { mailer_class: ..., mailer_method: "..." } 
data[:mailer_class].delay.send(mailer[:method])
```

This results in Sidekiq queueing up the `send` method which will eventually be called on my mailer.

Functionally it might work correctly, because that class after all will receive the appropriate method. But it feels a bit dirty and it interrupts other processes that watch the sidekiq queue because they expect to see a mailer method name but find `:send` instead.

Is there a good way around this or am I stuck modifying the rest of my application logic to work with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not pass that Hash to a Sidekiq Worker which knows how to send emails with that class/method combo?

```
def perform(hash)
  hash['mailer_class'].constantize.send(hash['mailer_method'])
end
```